# React state change from within button's click handler is preventing form submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider the code below:

```
function Item({name, _key})
{
   console.log('rendering Item')
   const [updatingName, setUpdatingName] = useState(false);
   const nameInputElement = useRef();

   useEffect(() => {
      if (updatingName) {
         nameInputElement.current.focus();
      }
   }, [updatingName]);

   function onUpdateClick() {
      setUpdatingName(true);
   }

   function onCancelClick() {
      setUpdatingName(false);
   }

   return (
      <div>
         <input ref={nameInputElement} type="text" defaultValue={name} name="name"
         disabled={!updatingName} />

         {!updatingName
         ? <>
            <button key={1} type="button" onClick={onUpdateClick}>Update</button>
            <button key={2} type="submit" name="delete" value={_key}>Remove</button>
         </>
         : <>
            <button key={3} type="submit" name="update" onClick={(e) => {setUpdatingName(false)}}>Save</button>
            <button key={4} type="button" onClick={onCancelClick}>Cancel</button>
         </>}
      </div>
   )
}

function ItemList({title})
{
   return <>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <form method="post" onSubmit={(e) => {console.log('submitting');e.preventDefault()}}>
         <Item name={'small'} _key={0} />
      </form>
   </>
}

export default ItemList;
```

The problem that I am facing is the click of the `Save` button. When it's clicked, as you can see, I trigger a state change. But at the same time, I also want the button to cause the underlying `<form>`'s submission.

(To check whether the form is submitted, I've prevented its default `submit` mechanism and instead gone with a simple log.)

However, it seems to be the case that when the state change is performed from within the `onClick` handler of the `Save` button, it ceases to submit the form. If I remove the state change from within the handler, it then does submit the form.

**Why is this happening?**

[Live CodeSandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/old-silence-l1jrlv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: If you apply onClick on the save button then it will trigger onClick rather than onSubmit of form. One simple thing you can do is don't apply a Onclick on Save button. Add       setUpdatingName(false) inside form onSubmit event

Comment: it still seems bit weird that it gets cancelled because the button gets removed *asynchronously*, so if you like you can even try file a github issue, to make sure this is not react bug.

Comment: Yeah that can be a good point @GiorgiMoniava

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `setUpdatingName(false)` in `save` button's click handler, the button is removed from the DOM before submitting. You can add the logic for showing the buttons in  `ItemList`, like below:

```js
function ItemList({ title }) {
  const [updatingName, setUpdatingName] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <h1>{title}</h1>
      <form
        method="post"
        onSubmit={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          setUpdatingName(false);
          console.log("submitting");
        }}
      >
        <Item
          name={"small"}
          _key={0}
          updatingName={updatingName}
          setUpdatingName={setUpdatingName}
        />
      </form>
    </>
  );
}

export default ItemList;
```

```js
function Item({ name, _key, updatingName, setUpdatingName }) {
  console.log("rendering Item");

  const nameInputElement = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (updatingName) {
      nameInputElement.current.focus();
    }
  }, [updatingName]);

  function onUpdateClick() {
    setUpdatingName(true);
  }

  function onCancelClick() {
    setUpdatingName(false);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        ref={nameInputElement}
        type="text"
        defaultValue={name}
        name="name"
        disabled={!updatingName}
      />

      {!updatingName ? (
        <>
          <button key={1} type="button" onClick={onUpdateClick}>
            Update
          </button>
          <button key={2} type="submit" name="delete" value={_key}>
            Remove
          </button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <button key={3} type="submit" name="update">
            Save
          </button>
          <button key={4} type="button" onClick={onCancelClick}>
            Cancel
          </button>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit angry-fast-upe615]

Also, you could use [`useTransition`](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useTransition) to ask React to delay the state update, so the submission happens first:

```js
function Item({ name, _key }) {
  console.log("rendering Item");
  const [isPending, startTransition] = useTransition();
  const [updatingName, setUpdatingName] = useState(false);
  const nameInputElement = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (updatingName) {
      nameInputElement.current.focus();
    }
  }, [updatingName]);

  function onUpdateClick() {
    setUpdatingName(true);
  }

  function onCancelClick() {
    setUpdatingName(false);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        ref={nameInputElement}
        type="text"
        defaultValue={name}
        name="name"
        disabled={!updatingName}
      />

      {!updatingName ? (
        <>
          <button key={1} type="button" onClick={onUpdateClick}>
            Update
          </button>
          <button key={2} type="submit" name="delete" value={_key}>
            Remove
          </button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <button
            key={3}
            type="submit"
            name="update"
            onClick={(e) => {
              startTransition(() => setUpdatingName(false));
            }}
          >
            Save
          </button>
          <button key={4} type="button" onClick={onCancelClick}>
            Cancel
          </button>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit angry-fast-upe615]

Comment: Yeah I also noticed it happened because the button was being removed, but the button was being removed *asynchronously*, so it still seemed weird to me that submit was still cancelled.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be the right explanation of the strange behavior. Thanks.

Comment: @yousoumar I find the asynchronous point in the first comment here quite reasonable. Why doesn't it matter?

Comment: @yousoumar In my comment I was just curious why the cancel happened despite the button removal being asynchronous. I didn't find  that explanation in your edit.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava maybe it's because React itself defers the submission of function until the desired state changes occur inside any of its children. Cuz as we know, React does tap into the internals of form behavior. But for a decisive explanation, I think I need to take this to the ReactJS repo.

Comment: Hi Giorgi and Coderboy! The fact that React is asynchronous, in my comprehension,  is more about being able to batch state updates and does not mean "update the state after the UI interactions are done", which would explain the definition of `useTransition` being "useTransition is a React Hook that lets you update the state without blocking the UI." But I'm not sure to have a solid explanation here, and I would love to see the answer you would get after filing an issue (please paste the link to the issue here for us).